# browsing throwing error replaceAll is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error on **chrome 84** somehow still not sure if it's the replaceAll method that is the problem or the function

*Intl.DateTimeFormat(...)
.resolvedOptions(...)
.timeZone.replaceAll* **is not a function**

```
function GetHumanTimezone() {
  return Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone.replaceAll('_', '-');
}
```

Comment: Is that `timeZone` property a string?  When you debug, what specifically is it?

Comment: Just a general note, but Chrome v84 is dangerously out of date and should be updated as soon as possible.

Comment: @David Yes It's a string

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll

Comment: So no, replaceAll is not supported by Chrome 84

Comment: BTW Which resolvedOptions.timezone has underscores?

Comment: MDN [suggests otherwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility) @mplungjan But only by a whisker.

Comment: Chrome 84 is also not supported in the MDN table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaceall is useless in my opinion. Just do `.timeZone.replace(/_/g, '-');`

but if you insist:

For your ancient Chrome you can do

```js
if (!"".replaceAll) String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
  var target = this;
  return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone.replaceAll("_", "-"))
```